# Output caching in IIS doesn't work for Wordpress php files

Tags: wordpress, caching, iis, outputcache

I enabled output caching for php files

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <serverRuntime frequentHitThreshold="1" frequentHitTimePeriod="00:00:30" />
      <caching>
         <profiles>
           <add extension="*.php" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:00:59" location="Any" varyByQueryString="*" />
         </profiles>
      </caching>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Caching works for PHP test file which prints time

http://www.ahangbaz.com/time.php

but it doesn't work for wordpress  (date is printed on page on 3rd line)

http://www.ahangbaz.com/index.php/4002/omega-el-producto/

I am not using any plugin in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

My guess as to why the second link is not cached is that the link does not *end* in `php`.

You might have better luck if you use a `*` extension. However, that might cache some things that you do not intend to cache.

Another alternative is to use a Wordpress plugin, such as [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/). I have not personally used it though.

See also: [Speed Up Wordpress On IIS 7](http://ruslany.net/2008/12/speed-up-wordpress-on-iis-70/)

Comment: with * is not working as well. I even tried with Wordpress PermaLink format of "index.php?id=4002" and didnt work

Comment: Same issue. There is a threshold under the appiclationhost config (root level) <serverRuntime>  --> frequentHitThreshold, and --> frequentHitTimePeriod

But even with those tuned to a super low threshold (1) and high time (5 mins), it STILL spins up the php fast-cgi process. 
I'll keep researching, and respond back if I find anything..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/web-server/tuning-iis-10

Looks like it requires you to enable the settings in registry. Can confirm functional after forcing those registry values into HTTP service parameters, and rebooting WWW service. The * extention for caching profile described in this answer is 100% correct. Indeed, you should not cache all, but must for extensionless wordpress. Recommend using Location derivatives (exclude wp-admin).